# Why use $PATH and what is it

Tags: path, terminal

I'm sort of new to programming (not really, but I'm still learning - aren't we all?). Although I know Java and Python and sort of know C, C++, JS, C#, HTML, CSS, etc. (and I can navigate pretty well in the terminal), I am not familiar with what $PATH is in the terminal.

I've been using the Linux terminal and Mac terminal much more frequently than I used to (if I even did at all two years ago), and I know for python, it wants you to "export" its path like `PATH=\path\to\python\bin:${PATH}\ export PATH`. However, I don't even know what it does. I tried to find out, but all I could find were people saying "export this path and export that one."

So, what is it and why use it? I understand that (if you do it for Python), it basically makes 'python'  (or 'python2' or 'python3') a variable, but I just don't understand the concept of what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man bash` describes it as:

> **PATH**
>
> > The  search  path for commands.  It is a colon-separated list of
> >                   directories in which the shell looks for commands  (see  COMMAND
> >                   EXECUTION  below).   A  zero-length (null) directory name in the
> >                   value of `PATH` indicates the current directory.  A null directory
> >                   name  may  appear  as  two  adjacent colons, or as an initial or
> >                   trailing colon.  The default path is  system-dependent,  and  is
> >                   set  by  the administrator who installs bash.  A common value is
> >                   `/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin'`.

When you run a command, like `python`, the operating system tries to find the `python` program in the list of directories stored in `PATH`.

Suppose your `PATH` is `/usr/local/bin:/foo:/bar:/baz:/usr/bin`. When you try to run the `python` comamnd, the operating system will look for an executable named `python` in those directories in order. On Linux, you can watch it do this with the `strace` command:

```
$ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/foo:/bar:/baz:/usr/bin strace -f /bin/bash -c 'python --version' 2>&1 | grep 'stat.*python'
stat("/usr/local/bin/python", 0x7fff98b63d00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/foo/python", 0x7fff98b63d00)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bar/python", 0x7fff98b63d00)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/baz/python", 0x7fff98b63d00)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/python", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=4864, ...}) = 0
```

As soon as `python` is found in `/usr/bin/python`, the search stops, and the program runs.

Comment: Cool. Thanks; I didn't know how to man it... I guess it makes since that it's under bash (btw, make sure you update :)... security problem with bash)