# Git bash always run 'export PATH=$PWD/node_modules/.bin:$PATH'

Tags: command-line-interface, git-bash

recently I have had this issue with my git bash which always runs command  
`export PATH=$PWD/node_modules/.bin:$PATH` 
 every time I open or start a new session. What is happening and what does the command mean? I'm quite new to CLI so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949636/why-use-path-and-what-is-it

Comment: Note that "git-bash" is merely a version of Bash that's bundled *with* Git. It has nothing to do with Git itself, it's just that Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell, and hence there's a port of bash to Windows to include with Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be because of a `~/.bashrc` resource file, executed when a new shell session is opened.
With a "Git bash", that implies a [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), which means '`~`' or `$HOME` is by default `%USERPROFILE%`.

Or you are using a VSCode extension like [`antfu/vscode-auto-npx`](https://github.com/antfu/vscode-auto-npx), in which case

> When you open up a terminal in VS Code, this extension injects `PATH` env variable with the local Node.js binaries.
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PWD/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
> ```

Comment: Thank you! The cause is really from that VSCode extension.